# Python - Estimativa da raiz quadrada

Tags: python, while, matemática

Boas, eu estava aqui a resolver um exercicio que o programa pede ao utilizador um número positivo e calcula a sua raiz quadrada utilizando:
+=(+ú/)/
 é uma estimativa para a raiz quadrada do número;
+ é a estimativa seguinte baseada na estimativa anterior.
A primeira estimativa da raiz quadrada deve ser  = ú/ .
O cálculo da próxima estimativa deve prosseguir enquanto a diferença |+−|>.

O código que tenho é:

```
# coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import math
print('Programa que calcula a raiz quadrada')
print()
while True:
    numero=eval(input('Introduza um número positivo: '))
    if 0<numero:
        break
    else:
        print('O número introduzido tem de ser positivo')
        print() 
Cont=0
Ri1=1
Ri=0
while abs(Ri1-Ri)>0.0001:
    if Cont==0:
        Ri=numero/2
        Cont=Cont+1
    else:
        Ri1=(Ri+numero/Ri)/2
        Ri=Ri1
        Cont=Cont+1
print(numero)
print(Cont)
print(Ri1)
```

Como ainda estou no inicio da programação só posso usar if e while.
Supostamente a Estimativa 1 = Ri=numero/2
Estimativa 2 = =(+ú/)/
Estimativa 3 = +=(+ú/)/
...
um dos resultados que deveria dar seria: Numero=2;Numero de Estimativas =5; Resultado=1.414214

Comment: Qual o erro que você está encontrando?

Comment: não me está a dar erro, mas o resultado está a dar errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve salvar a última aproximação antes de calcular a próxima:

```
[...]
    else:
        Ri1=(Ri+numero/Ri)/2
        Ri=Ri1
        Cont=Cont+1
[...]
```

Na segunda linha, o comando `Ri=Ri1` faz os dois números serem iguais, ou seja, assim que sair do loop, a diferença entre eles vai ser 0.

Experimente inverter a ordem das linhas:

```
[...]
    else:
        Ri=Ri1
        Ri1=(Ri+numero/Ri)/2
        Cont=Cont+1
[...]
```

Rodando, encontramos o resultado desejado:

```
Programa que calcula a raiz quadrada

Introduza um número positivo: 81
81
8
9.000000000007091
```

Outro problema encontrado, é que seu chute inicial de `Ri1` já é 1. Isto é, caso `numero` seja 2, a primeira aproximação vai ser 1 e vai sair do laço logo na primeira iteração. Uma dica, seria dar o valor inicial das variáveis correto desde o começo:

```
Cont=1
Ri1=numero/2
Ri = 0
while abs(Ri-Ri1)>0.0001:
    Ri=Ri1
    Ri1= (Ri1+numero/Ri1)/2
    Cont=Cont+1
```

Comment: Acabei de testar com o seu número introduzido (81) e o resultado dá o pretendido mas quando coloco numero=2 o resultado já dá errado visto que com numero=2 os resultados deveriam ser: numero=2, cont=5, Ri1=1.414214... e o resultado que me está a dar é numero=2, cont=1, Ri1=1

Comment: Sim. É um erro pois o primeiro chute é ```R = numero/2```. Como você deu o valor inicial da variável ```Ri1``` de 1, coincide com o primeiro chute e o while já retorna falso. Editei a minha resposta para incluir uma solução para isso também.